# Racket and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, lisp, racket

I would like to use OpenCV with the Racket programming language. I normally use Python but would like to use Racket so that I can start using it for computer vision projects. However, I do not know how to use/link the OpenCV library with/to Racket. Please could you assist me with this if you know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/oetr/racket-opencv/tree/master/tutorials
and https://github.com/tonyg/racket-opencv-videocapture

I have tried neither of them.

The first project has ported some of the Open CV tutorials,
which could a starting point.

https://github.com/oetr/racket-opencv/tree/master/tutorials

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful